# Check if all returned arrays contains the values false

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
console.log(allStatuses);
```

This variable returns two arrays:

```
[true, false, false, false, false]

[true, false, false, true, false]
```

Sometimes more arrays will be returned with `true/false` values.

I would like to check if all the returned arrays contain `false` and if so, do something.

What would be the best way to get this done?

Here is the code responsible:

```
angular.forEach($scope.prefAccount, function(account){
     if (typeof account === 'object') {
          var allStatuses = [];  
          angular.forEach(account, function(alertStatus){
               return allStatuses.push(alertStatus.enabled);
          })
          console.log(allStatuses);
     }                    
});
```

Comment: So, is `allStatuses` an array of arrays containing a set of 'true', 'false' values?

Comment: May you post your actual code?

Comment: Each array contains at least one false? Or all falses?

Comment: If all the arrays returned contain false. So no true at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (*to create one-dimensional array from two-dimensional*)

```
var allStatuses = [
  [true, false, false, false, false],
  [true, false, false, true, false]
]
allStatuses = [].concat.apply([], allStatuses);

var isFalse = allStatuses.every(function (el) {
  return el === false;
})

console.log(isFalse);
```

Comment: Def the best answer! +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100392/discussion-between-emporio-and-alexander).

Answer (score 3):

The shortest, most semantic version would be:

```
allStatuses.every(a => !a.some(Boolean))
```

Or without arrow functions:

```
allStatuses.every(function(a) { return !a.some(Boolean); })
```

In English:

> *Every* array in `allStatuses` should not have *some* (any) true values.